# How to hide controller name in URL when using multiple controllers in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question regarding routing in ASP.NET, MVC. If I use two or more controllers, how can I go about routing to hide both the controllernames in the URL? I've managed to hide the first controllername, but it gets tricky when I want to hide the second one.

I figured it might not be possible since the webserver needs to know what controller to look for, therefor they require different routes in the URL, but it should be possible for the API to find the appropriate controller by just having the action-name data availible?

RouteConfig.cs:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "proj",
           url: "p/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Project" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "login" }
       );
```

The urls look as follows depending on which controller I'm in:

```
http://localhost:56590/create       <- AccessController
http://localhost:56590/p/overview   <- ProjectController
```

This is how I want it to look when I browse the site:

```
http://localhost:56590/create       <- AccessController
http://localhost:56590/overview     <- ProjectController
```

How can I achieve this using routing, if even possible?

Thanks alot for any explanation :)

Comment: `url: "create", defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "Create" }`, and the same for `overview`?

Comment: @CodeCaster, is this the only way? It means I'd have to add routes for every page in each controller?

Comment: You'll have to "default" both action and controller for every route. But why? It easier to implement only `Index` action, set it up as default, and leave controller name in route.

Comment: Okay, I thought so. Yea it's not a problem leaving the controller name in route seeing as I can rename it as I've already did, so it looks alright. Thanks for the explanation :)